# Vuejs post does not find NodeJs Express server/action

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, vue.js

I'm trying to send data using vue.js to my node.js server, but the browser console keeps showing me a 404: `POST http://127.0.0.1:63342/myaction 404 (Not Found)`

vue.js:

```
this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:63342/myaction', this.formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response.body);
}
```

node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exp = express();

exp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

exp.post('/myaction', function (req, res) {
    res.send('saved: "' + req.body.name + '".');    
});

exp.listen(63342, function () {
    console.log('Server running at', this.address());
});
```

When I start my server, it says it's running at `{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 63342 }`

The `POST` worked without vue.js, by simply submitting a HTML `form`, but now AJAX doesn't wordk. I tried multiple ports and folders, but can't figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. You have to manually add an address to the listener:

`app.listen(63342, '127.0.0.1', function () {}`

And in my case I was using the same port for API and Frontend, I had to switch ports and allow [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)